# Is this statement grammatically correct - "I have spent too long confusing nice for good"

Tags: prepositions

My confusion is whether the right way of writing this would be "confused X **with** Y" or "confused X **for** Y"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant sense of *confuse* (verb) is #5 in OED:

> To mix up in the mind, to fail to distinguish, erroneously regard as identical, mistake one for another; = CONFOUND *v.* 7.

The one example given with preposition uses *with:*

> 1862   J. Ruskin *Munera Pulveris* (1880) 29   We in reality confuse wealth with money.

Note that the definition itself features *mistake . . . for.*

There is little rhyme or reason to the association of certain words with certain prepositions in English (and no definitive reference work on the matter, such as I believe Duden has provided for German), but strong preferences have indeed established themselves. I would suggest using *with* with *confuse* and *for* with *mistake:*

- I have spent too long confusing nice with good.
- I have spent too long mistaking nice for good.

See also this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=confusing%20it%20with%2C%20confusing%20it%20for%2C%20mistaking%20it%20with%2C%20mistaking%20it%20for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) of relative frequencies in books scanned by Google and published 1800–2000.

Answer (score 0):

*With* is correct when using 'confused'. You might use *for* with 'swap' or 'exchange', but confusingly enough you could also use 'with' in those cases as well.

Answer (score 0):

> I have spent too long conflating nice and good.
>
> Conflation occurs when the identities of two or more individuals,
>   concepts, or places, sharing some characteristics of one another, seem
>   to be a single identity

Comment: I meant the statement not in the way of thinking the two to be the same, but mistaking one for the other. In that, whenever I saw someone nice, I thought they were also good. Is it still conflating?